# How to make expression '&'-binding with optional initialization

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-components

I want to initialize a callback &-property binding to a function that returns true (if no callback was passed). Something like this:

```
export const DatepickerInputComponent = {
    bindings: {
        validityCheck: '&',
    },
    templateUrl: './datepicker-input.component.html',
    controller: class DatepickerInputController implements ng.IController {
        validityCheck: Function = (args) => true; // <- doesn't work
        validate(value: Date): void {
            // some validations
            return this.validityCheck({ selection: value });
        }
    },
}
```

When calling validate() from a component with no `validityCheck` property defined, it will return undefined. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Probably instead of overwriting `validityCheck` in the controller you can return something like this `return !angular.isFunction(this.validityCheck) || this.validityCheck({ selection: value });` in your `validate` method. Use `&?` to make the binding optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making your binding optional:

```
bindings: {
    validityCheck: '&?'
},
```

Comment: Thanks,  was it the first part or the second part which fixed it for you?

Comment: First part nailed it, console.log spits out `ƒ (){return!0}`. Thanks!

Comment: Cool.  Have you tried passing in a value for validityCheck aswell?  I would be a little surprised if that worked.

Comment: Yeah, that works just fine. It's how the datepicker component 'talks' to its rangepicker parent component. React-style I guess.

Answer (score -1):

As the term `binding` suggest, it has to be passed in from parent component.

```
<date-picker-input-component
  format="some string"
  mode="some other string"
  validity-check="someFunctionFromParentController">
</date-picker-input-component>
```

And remove this part from your controller

```
validityCheck: Function = (args) => { return true; }; // <- doesn't work
```

Assumption is `someFunctionFromParentController` is defined on your parent controller